# Which layout should be in landscape in android?

Tags: android, landscape, dashboard

I have downloaded the google io application and I noticed that for landscape layout, its only the dashboard layout that have a landscape layout (in the layout-land folder).
My question is the following, is it for all the layout available in our project that we must create a landscape layout or it is only for the dashboard layout?

Thanks.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to create a landscape layout for any layout in your app. You should do this when you want to have a different layout in portrait vs. landscape. Sounds to me like the Google IO app specifies a different landscape layout for only one screen (the home screen/dashboard), presumably because that's the only screen the developers felt needed a different landscape layout. Point is, it's up to you which screens have alternate layouts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you have to show. 
Sometimes there is more data which can be shown because of extra width in landscape and you have to compress data vertically in landscape. For such cases use different layouts